# Emacs indentation does not identify variables in Python-mode

Tags: python, r, emacs, indentation

So I really like how Emacs automatically colors variables in Python. However, when there is indentation (e.g. within a `for` loop), it does not color the syntax anymore. Is there an easy solution (same holds for R)?

EDIT (because of comment): You can see how var1 gets a color, but within a function a variable assignment does not.

[image]

Comment: Which major mode are you using for your python files?

Comment: python-mode, `(defgroup python nil
  "Silly walks in the Python language."
  :group 'languages
  :version "22.1" ... ... ... ... `

Comment: There are two independent python-mode implementations, the one that ships with emacs, and one that does not.  https://launchpad.net/python-mode/  I use the second one, you seem to be using the first one.

Comment: @Dualinity [It renders on my system](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VkB5p.png) when using `emacs -q` and `M-x python-mode`. I use GNU Emacs 24.1.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.12) of 2012-09-22 on batsu, modified by Debian in Ubuntu 12.10. What version do you use and what mode? Also, does it happen if you start Emacs with `emacs -q`?

Comment: @N.N. Same thing happens with -q. To be honest, I do not see `var2` get color in your example?

Comment: @tcaswell Are you sure it works on the "second" one? (I can't find a distinction)

Comment: @Dualinity You are right. I made the mistake of putting a space between `var` and `1`. When I correct the mistake I get the same coloring problem as you.

Answer (score 0):

It [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siftt.png) with Python mode that comes with Emacs 24.3.1. Upgrade your Emacs and the problem will go away.

(Function and variable being the same color is due to using the "solarized" theme.)